# syntax error in sql server 2008 for AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am using microsoft sql-server 2008 for creating database tables... I am using the following commands to create the table. but it is giving the syntax error 
incorrect syntax near `AUTO_INCREMENT`

code:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name NOT NULL varchar(255),
Description varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Perhaps you should stick with the SQL Server [`IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `IDENTITY` instead of `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

write this way:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),

Name varchar(255) NOT NULL ,

Description varchar(255),

PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```